# When is function argument conversion done?

Tags: c, arguments, type-conversion

Assume I declare like this:

```
void foo(uint64_t);
```

And this function is defined in an external assembly file. Now I call it like this from C code:

```
uint32_t x = 42;
foo(x);
```

When is `x` cast to a `uint64_t`? Can I rely on my assembly code always receiving a `uint64_t` in whatever register/stack location is mandated by the relevant target's ABI, or must I do the cast myself?

In other words, are `foo(x)` and `foo((uint64_t)x)` equivalent when the function definition is not available to the compiler? It might be a stupid question but I am not sure what really happens here.

Comment: I edited the title for the vocabulary. In C standard jargon, a cast is an "explicit conversion". It seems that you are just asking for the "implicit conversions".

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, it's **never** *cast* to an `uint64_t`, I don't see any *typecasting* happening in that code. Instead, it's **promoted** to `uint64_t`, and yes, it always happens automatically (according to "usual arithmetic conversions", as the Standard's phrasing goes). So, **you don't need to cast it manually.**

> In other words, are `foo(x)` and `foo((uint64_t)x)` equivalent when the function definition is not available to the compiler?

They are if it's only the **definition** that's unavailable. If the **declaration** is missing though, that's a different story... (and you should not be doing that! - it will invoke undefined behavior, since `uint32_t` will be assumed as the type of the argument, which it isn't.)

Comment: Yes, the declaration itself is always there - but the function is written in assembly, so the function's definition is normally unavailable to the compiler. Thanks, that makes a lot of sense :)

Comment: @Thomas you're welcome. Declarations are always enough. **This** is **the** purpose of declarations. (If the compiler needed the definition, that would be quite an ugly mess!)

Comment: Just for the vocabulary, in the C standard jargon this is in fact not "promotion" but "conversion". "Integer promotion" are the rules that are in effect when there is not prototype in scope, the thing that narrow types are promoted to `int` and stuff like that.

Answer (score 1):

In c11 specification 6.5.2.2-4:

> In preparing for the call to a function, the arguments are evaluated, and each parameter is assigned the value of the corresponding argument.

So `x` is casted (promoted?, converted?) to a `uint64_t` **before** the function call.

Comment: No, it's never "casted". It's promoted.

Comment: In fact, it's never "cast". :)

Comment: @H2CO3 It is “converted”, not “promoted”.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid typecasting it explicitly because it gets **promoted** itself to `uint64_t`

**Edit:**
@H2CO3's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17630325/1906361) explains pretty good this thing.

Comment: What happens to a function argument is *conversion*, not *promotion*. `void f(int x); f(1LL);` causes `1LL` to be converted to `int`, but going from `long long` to `int` is hardly a “promotion”.